# Parsing HTML from a JSON String with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have no idea what im doing wrong, but I have a JSON string with this:

```
jsonp443489({"content":"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Title</title></head><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>"});
```

I need to parse this to be able to modify the content. Like, for example, id want to grab the `<p>`'s content.

Now, in jQuery if i do:

```
console.log($(json.content).html());
```

It returns `Title`.

If i do:

```
console.log($('p',json.content));
```

It returns `[]`, or, an empty array.

Finally, if I do just:
    console.log($(json.content));

It returns `[<title>​Title​</title>​,<p>​Hello World​</p>​]`

Which is fine, but then I cant do `.find()` or anything. Since I wont know what the HTML will be, i cant use `$(json.content)[1]`.

Any ideas?

**==UPDATE==**

After hacking at this for a couple hours i decided to try XML. My example XML was:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><doc><item>One</item><item>Two</item></doc>
```

It was giving me the same grief, then it hit me, its a JS object, not a string and jQuery is expecting a string. I went and did

```
$(JSON.stringify(json.content)).find('item')
```

And voila! I got an array of two items. I was pretty excited but then when I went and tried it with HTML again (using the JSONP return HTML snippet above):

```
console.log($(JSON.stringify(json.content)).find('p'));
```

I still get an empty array. It's driving me mad... Any more ideas?

Comment: Can you more clearly define what your questions is here.

Comment: Ill try... but the question really is, how do you parse HTML from a JSON string :) but ill think of how to reword this...

Comment: Just FYI, this `JSON.stringify(json.content)` is unnecessary. `json.content` is already a string (XML). If you pass a string to `JSON.stringify` it just returns the same string. Maybe you should read up about about JavaScript objects and JSON first...

Comment: No, it does not return the same string. Throw up that XML on JSFiddle, make a JSONP request, and parse it as is ( `$(xml).find('item')` ). It wont work. Convert it with `JSON.stringify` then pass it in. It'll work. Ive been doing JS a long time and jQuery for going on 4 years. If the answer is so simple, and its just because I dont understand JS objects and JSON, give me a JSFiddle or JSBin link and just tell me how to do it rather than bashing my JS knowledge.

Comment: You are right, it is not the same string. `JSON.stringify` will add quotation marks `"` to the beginning and end of the string. So instead of `<?xml ...` you get `"<?xml ..."`. It nevertheless works without it: http://jsfiddle.net/MYNVj/ And I'm sorry if it seemed like that, but I did not intend to rant about your knowledge...

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better way, but this works (retrieves the `p` elements):

```
$('<div />', {html: json.content}).find('p');
```

Comment: That wouldnt work right tho, would it? I mean, the HTML contains the DOCTYPE, head, etc and wrapping it in a div seems... naughty haha

Comment: @Oscar: Invalid markup will be dropped. What you will end up with is `<div><title>...</title><p>...</p></div>`. I agree it is not pretty, but remember that you never add the `div` to the DOM of the page.

Answer (score -1):

What is jsonp443489 here? Why not just do $.parseJSON ?

Once you have done that you should be able to access content inside it and then create a jquery object from that content and search in it.

var json = $.parseJSON(jsoncontent);
$(json.content).find('');// or you can add it to dom and search using $('#id')

Comment: That is from getjson. :) that's what a jsonp request returns. Also you can't set a var to Ajax content since it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Oops I read it as getjson not parsejson. Let me try that. Thanks

Comment: any idea why "`var json = $.parseJSON(json);`" then `console.log(json)` would return null? The JSON should be well formed...

Comment: @Oscar: `json` is already a JavaScript object, not a string. You cannot parse a JS object to a JS object.

Comment: I know, i just thought jQuery had some magic in it. I figured thats why you suggested it.