# get html from json object and display on page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

if I have some html that is encoded in json format. How can I get back my html in order to display it on a page or something? json_decode does not seem to work

Thank you

Comment: Provide some code

Comment: I believe `stringify()`? Not entirely sure because no code.

Comment: How is the HTML encoded?

Comment: json_decode is a php method, are you trying to decode it in php?

Comment: Here's a related question about parsing html from json:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084505/parsing-html-from-a-json-string-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

you can decode it in jquery using **parseJSON()**